# Font not working in Microsoft Edge or IE

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I imported a font stored on my computer into a CSS file and, although it works in Chrome, it doesn't in Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer. I don't have any other browsers so I can't check with those and I was wondering if anyone would know why.

Linking CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Linotte';
    src: url('...\font\Linotte\Linotte.otf') format('otf'),
         url('...\font\Linotte\Linotte.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('...\font\Linotte\Linotte.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I read that Edge doesn't have .woff2 support, so I figured linking both the .otf and .woff versions would help, but it hasn't. I get the following error in my Chrome console on any page that uses this font for both the .woff and .woff2:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

However, that error doesn't show up in the Edge console or the IE console.

When I go into sources, this is what shows up (won't let me imbed images yet, I'm very new): [Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhInz.png)

The folder the Linotte folder is in is in the same folder as the folder the CSS sheet is in, so I don't understand why it isn't showing the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the three `...` with `..`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Linotte';
    src: url('..\font\Linotte\Linotte.otf') format('otf'),
         url('..\font\Linotte\Linotte.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('..\font\Linotte\Linotte.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also the convention is to use forward slashes, not backward.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. For some reason I thought it'd be the same as how it appears in File Explorer, not an actual URL.